# python create a class with complex numbers

Tags: python

i have done this in c++ but i am trying it to python and have difficulties.I did this code:

```
class mycomplex:
def __init__(self,real=None,imag=None):
    self.real=real
    self.imag=imag

def read_data(self):
    self.real=input("Give the real part :")
    self.imag=input("Give the imag part :")

def addition(self,complex):
    return mycomplex(self.real+complex.real,self.imag+complex.imag)


def __str__(self):
    return ("{0} {1} {2} {3}{4}".format("The complex is : ",self.real,"+",self.imag,"j"))


if __name__=="__main__":

a=mycomplex()
b=mycomplex()
a.read_data()
b.read_data()
print(a)
print(b)
c=a.addition(b)
print(c)
```

1) First of all it doesn't work because i have in  the init method 2 arguments and when i try to create an instance with  a=mycomplex() it gives me an error of course.Can i handle this in some way without changing the init ?

2) In order for me to understand i want to use the addition method with 2 ways like i say in the code.It will help me i think.It's different to say a.addition() and c=a.addition(b).

3) If you have any better suggestions from implementing the above,please say it.I think you understand what i am trying to show you.

Thank you!

Comment: You're calling your init method without arguments - if you want to do that, don't put parameters in the init method.

Comment: Also missing `self.`'s in your read_data method.

Comment: I tried it but then how will it recognize the real and imag parts?It gives "global name real not defined"

Comment: @AustinMarshall, as far as I know, python doesn't complain about semicolons.

Comment: Are you trying to set the values when you instantiate the object, or afterwards when you call `read_data`?  You can do both if you want, but if you include parameters in your `__init__` you should set the values.  Otherwise, don't bother with an `__init__` method.

Comment: @Thomas:Can i have in the init method the inputs?How can i do that because i must declare first self.real=real,self.imag=imag.And then,how to implement the input?I mean if i try real=input(...)it conflicts.

Comment: See Adrien, Loïc, or Austin's answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) yes you can make it work by using default values:

```
def __init__(self,real=0,imag=0):
    ...
```

the default values specified in the function signature will be used in place of the missing arguments.

2) i do not understand your first way of writing an addition: when you write `a.addition()`, what are you adding to `a` ?

the second way (`a.addition(b)`) is pretty clear, but you need to change the way you define `addition()`:

```
def addition(self,complex):
    return mycomplex(real+complex.real,imag+complex.imag)
```

Comment: Ok,thanks it works!Just one things.1) In the above  addition method you wrote,it needs self.real not real.But i can't understand this!In the init method i declare self.real=real.Why i need to put self.real again in all the methods?Thank you!

Comment: Because only in the init method does the variable `real` exist - it comes from the `__init__` parameter.  Everywhere else, instance variables (prefaced by `self.`) are our only way to access the information we stored in this object during the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 2):

Python has implemented complex numbers by default.

See [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html) or [here](http://docs.python.org/c-api/complex.html) or [here](http://docs.python.org/c-api/complex.html).

### Edit: Maybe you are interested in the following:

Your `read_data` won't work correctly because of the following:

`real = input(..)` creates a new local variable `real`. You probably want to modify `self.real`, thus you should write `self.real = float(input(...))`, and should convert this to float.

Moreover, your constructor needs you to give it 2 arguments. Thus, you should call `mycomplex(1,2)` (or other values). If you want default values, you can change `__init__` to `def __init__(self, real=0, imag=0)`.

For readability, you could define a method [`__add__(self, other)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types). Then, you can use `x+y` for your complex numbers.

Comment: I know but i want to do it myself!

Answer (score 1):

python features a built-in complex type, readily available. try typing `5+3j + 8+4j` in a python interpreter...

Comment: I know but i want to do it myself!

Answer (score 0):

You can default to `None` in your `__init__()`:

```
def __init__(self, real=None, imag=None):
    if real is not None:
        self.real=real
    else:
        self.real=0

    if imag is not None:
        self.imag=imag
    else:
        self.imag=0
```

Then you can call `mycomplex()` without any arguments, and the `real` and `imag` components will be 0.

You may also want to consider implementing a `__add__()` function instead of `addition()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may change your code to this :

```
def __init__(self,real=None,imag=None):
    self.real=real;
    self.imag=imag;

def read_data(self):
    self.real=input("Give the real part :")
    self.imag=input("Give the imag part :")
```